# ajax and http denying request

Tags: jquery, node.js

I am trying to send a post request from the client side to the server using ajax and HTTP. The problem I'm having is even though I set the cors options it's still denying me access to the back end. Where did I go wrong? What im trying to do is send data to back end then once accepted send data back to client saying its successful. I can do this properly with express but I am trying to do this with HTTP. Any help is appreciated. Thanks in advance.

EDIT: The CORS issue has been fixed as suggested in the comments but when I try to log the data sent from the client-side it returns undefined what is the right way to log the data sent from the client. What I tried was `req.body`

```js
$('.testBtn').on('click', function() {
  const currentOpenRequestName = $('.testInput').val()
  if (currentOpenRequestName != '') {
    $.ajax({
      url: 'http://reqres.in/api/users',
      type: 'POST',
      "crossDomain": true,
      headers: {
        "accept": "application/json",
        "Access-Control-Allow-Origin": "*"
      },
      data: {
        'currentOpenRequestName': currentOpenRequestName
      },
      success: function(data) {
        console.log(data)
      }
    })
  }
})
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input class="testInput" />
<button class="testBtn">click me</button>
```

```js
onst http = require('http')
const hostname = 'reqres.in';
const path = '/api/users';
const port = 3000;


const server = http.createServer((req, res) => {

  res.setHeader('Access-Control-Allow-Origin', '*');
  res.setHeader('Access-Control-Allow-Methods', 'OPTIONS, POST, GET');
  res.setHeader('Access-Control-Max-Age', 2592000);

  //log the data sent from the client side
  console.log(req.body)
  //send string back to client
  res.end("successFull")

});

server.listen(port, hostname, () => {
  console.log(`Server running at http://${hostname}:${port}/`);
})
```

Comment: `"Access-Control-Allow-Origin": "*"` is useless on the Ajax call, the server needs to set it.

Comment: You are making a POST, CORS is set for Options and Get

Comment: @epascarello its still denying me access even though i allowed cors in the sever too.

Comment: And my second comment tells you why

Comment: silly me you are right 1 more question req.body is returning undefined what is the way to get the data sent from client in HTTP? res.end worked perfectly. @epascarello